# Referencing a GameObject Tag through Validation in Unity C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where you have to move boxes by dragging them. But right now all objects can move and not just boxes. I'm trying to use validation through tags to get this working, but can't quite figure it out. This is my validation code.

```
    {

        //Mouse Button Press Down
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            getTarget = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);
            if (getTarget != GameObject.tag("Box"))
            {
                isMouseDragging = true;
                //Converting world position to screen position.
                positionOfScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(getTarget.transform.position);
                offsetValue = getTarget.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z));
            }
        }

        //Mouse Button Up
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isMouseDragging = false;
        }

        //Is mouse Moving
        if (isMouseDragging)
        {
            //tracking mouse position.
            Vector3 currentScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z);

            //converting screen position to world position with offset changes.
            Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentScreenSpace) + offsetValue;

            //It will update target gameobject's current postion.
            getTarget.transform.position = currentPosition;
        }


    }

    //Method to Return Clicked Object
    GameObject ReturnClickedObject(out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject target = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit))
        {
            target = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
        return target;
    }
```

if anyone can figure out how to help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `getTarget != GameObject.tag("Box")`--is this valid code? I don't have Unity handy to check, but I think it should be `getTarget.tag == "Box"`?

Comment: I second @xander 's point. getTarget is a GameObject, and you are comparing it with a tag (a string) of another GameObject.

Comment: @xander is correct, I was referencing it wrong. It works fine now, thank you both!